Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' during Singleton destruction in Spring Boot
I’m encountering an issue in my Spring Boot application that uses Redis. The error occurs during the application shutdown, specifically with the following message:
Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)

From my understanding, this error arises when a Bean is being destroyed, but another Bean is attempted to be created during the destruction process. Below is the configuration for my Redis @Bean:
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories(keyspaceConfiguration = MyKeyspaceConfiguration.class)
public class RedisConfig {
    @Value("${spring.redis.cluster.nodes}")
    private String clusterNodes;
    @Value("${spring.redis.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${spring.redis.cluster.max-redirects}")
    private int maxRedirects;
    @Value("${spring.redis.username}")
    private String username;

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisClusterConfiguration clusterConfig = new RedisClusterConfiguration(
                Arrays.asList(clusterNodes.split(",")));
        clusterConfig.setMaxRedirects(maxRedirects);
        clusterConfig.setUsername(username);
        clusterConfig.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(password));
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(clusterConfig);
    }

    @Lazy
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
}

I have methods that interact with Redis as well:
private AuthenticationResponse getAuthenticationResponse() {
    log.info("Access token is not found in Redis or expired! Expire time :{} ", LocalDateTime.now());
    AuthenticationResponse authentication = login();
    redisConfig.redisTemplate().opsForValue().set("accessToken", authentication.getAccessToken(), expirationTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return authentication;
}

private String getBearerTokenFromRedis() {
    try {
        if (redisConfig == null || redisConfig.redisTemplate() == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Redis configuration or template is not available.");
        }
        String accessToken = Objects.requireNonNull(redisConfig.redisTemplate().opsForValue().get("keyxx")).toString();
        return getBearerToken(accessToken);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        AuthenticationResponse authentication = getAuthenticationResponse();
        return getBearerToken(authentication.getAccessToken());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("getBearerTokenFromRedis ERROR! {}", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

Problem:
The error happens when the Spring Boot application is shutting down. I suspect this is related to the Redis configuration or perhaps the lifecycle of beans. From what I understand, Spring is trying to create a new bean while destroying the redisTemplate bean.
Questions:
What could be causing this issue during the shutdown process?
Is there something wrong with my Redis configuration, particularly with the way I’m creating beans or interacting with them in my methods?
How can I resolve this error?
Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Add the full stacktrace not just a snippet.

In which thread does the Exception occur?

@SpaceTrucker  Img
I also catch the exception in the img.

@M.Deinum Thank you for your suggestion. Currently, I am only logging the exception message using e.getMessage(). Here is the error message I captured:
Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!
However, I'm not logging the full stacktrace at the moment. If needed, I can update the code to include the full stacktrace. Any advice based on the current information would be appreciated.

The information needs to be added to your question as text and never as an image. I and probably many other users won't click on a link to some dubious website they don't know about.

Never just log a message, the stacktrace includes important information for debugging. You are hindering yourself if you don't. Please log the full error stacktrace.

@SpaceTrucker  Thank you for the feedback. I apologize for any inconvenience. Below is the information directly included in the question as text:
catch (Exception e) {             log.error("getBearerTokenFromRedis ERROR! {}", e.getMessage());             return null;         }
I am burning from general exception

@M.Deinum Adding printStacktrace takes too long. I can't get the error locally either.

You can post the same piece of code 3 times but that isn't providing more information. We need the stacktrace. Also don't use printStacktrace use the logging. Do log.error(message, e) that will print the needed information. Tip for the future never just log the message as you loose valuable information for debugging/problem solving.
